# Nifi Registry 0.8 throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item

Tags: java-15, corretto, apache-nifi-registry

I am trying to run Nifi Registry 0.8 on Windows Server 2019 using Amazon Corretto 15. I am aware that Nifi Registry is not officially support on Windows but some sources say it should run. Nifi Registry should also support Java 15. Both the path to Java and Nifi Registry do not have space in them.

When I try to run the run run-nifi-registry.bat, I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:569)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:257)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.nifi.registry.jetty.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:481)
    at org.apache.nifi.registry.NiFiRegistry.<init>(NiFiRegistry.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.registry.NiFiRegistry.main(NiFiRegistry.java:164)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:468)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:571)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:363)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:582)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create JAXBContext.
    at org.apache.nifi.registry.security.authorization.AuthorizerFactory.initializeJaxbContext(AuthorizerFactory.java:100)
    at org.apache.nifi.registry.security.authorization.AuthorizerFactory.<clinit>(AuthorizerFactory.java:91)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:131)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:318)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:478)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:435)
    at org.apache.nifi.registry.security.authorization.AuthorizerFactory.initializeJaxbContext(AuthorizerFactory.java:98)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:555)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:92)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:125)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:128)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

I found this article during my research and checked the pom.xml in the source code (source downloaded just for investigation, I am using the downloaded zip version)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

When I tried to look into this further, I found the following in the logs:

```
2021-07-15 10:51:24,625 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader WAP webapp loaded class javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder
2021-07-15 10:51:24,625 DEBUG [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext isSystemResource==true javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil$ExceptionHandler jar:file:/C:/ApacheNifi/nifi-registry-0.8.0/work/jetty/nifi-registry-web-api-0.8.0.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/javax/xml/bind/ServiceLoaderUtil$ExceptionHandler.class
2021-07-15 10:51:24,625 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader WAP webapp loaded class javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil$ExceptionHandler
2021-07-15 10:51:24,625 DEBUG [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext isSystemResource==true javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder$1 jar:file:/C:/ApacheNifi/nifi-registry-0.8.0/work/jetty/nifi-registry-web-api-0.8.0.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/javax/xml/bind/ContextFinder$1.class
2021-07-15 10:51:24,626 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader WAP webapp loaded class javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder$1
2021-07-15 10:51:24,626 DEBUG [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext isSystemResource==true javax.xml.bind.GetPropertyAction jar:file:/C:/ApacheNifi/nifi-registry-0.8.0/work/jetty/nifi-registry-web-api-0.8.0.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/javax/xml/bind/GetPropertyAction.class
2021-07-15 10:51:24,627 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader WAP webapp loaded class javax.xml.bind.GetPropertyAction
2021-07-15 10:51:24,627 DEBUG [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext isSystemResource==true javax.xml.bind.ModuleUtil jar:file:/C:/ApacheNifi/nifi-registry-0.8.0/work/jetty/nifi-registry-web-api-0.8.0.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/META-INF/versions/9/javax/xml/bind/ModuleUtil.class
2021-07-15 10:51:24,627 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader WAP webapp loaded class javax.xml.bind.ModuleUtil
2021-07-15 10:51:24,628 DEBUG [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext isServerClass==false class java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory
2021-07-15 10:51:24,628 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader WAP parent loaded class java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory
2021-07-15 10:51:24,628 DEBUG [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext isSystemResource==false org.apache.nifi.registry.security.authorization.generated.ObjectFactory jar:file:/C:/ApacheNifi/nifi-registry-0.8.0/work/jetty/nifi-registry-web-api-0.8.0.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/nifi-registry-framework-0.8.0.jar!/org/apache/nifi/registry/security/authorization/generated/ObjectFactory.class
2021-07-15 10:51:24,628 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader WAP webapp loaded class org.apache.nifi.registry.security.authorization.generated.ObjectFactory
2021-07-15 10:51:24,629 DEBUG [main] javax.xml.bind Resolved classes from context path: [class org.apache.nifi.registry.security.authorization.generated.ObjectFactory]
2021-07-15 10:51:24,629 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader getResource org/apache/nifi/registry/security/authorization/generated/jaxb.properties null
2021-07-15 10:51:24,629 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader getResource org/apache/nifi/registry/security/authorization/generated/jaxb.properties null
2021-07-15 10:51:24,629 DEBUG [main] javax.xml.bind Checking system property javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory
2021-07-15 10:51:24,629 DEBUG [main] javax.xml.bind   not found
2021-07-15 10:51:24,629 DEBUG [main] javax.xml.bind Checking system property javax.xml.bind.context.factory
2021-07-15 10:51:24,629 DEBUG [main] javax.xml.bind   not found
2021-07-15 10:51:24,629 DEBUG [main] javax.xml.bind Checking system property javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
2021-07-15 10:51:24,629 DEBUG [main] javax.xml.bind   not found
2021-07-15 10:51:24,629 DEBUG [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext isSystemResource==true javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory jar:file:/C:/ApacheNifi/nifi-registry-0.8.0/work/jetty/nifi-registry-web-api-0.8.0.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContextFactory.class
2021-07-15 10:51:24,630 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader WAP webapp loaded interface javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory
2021-07-15 10:51:24,630 DEBUG [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext isSystemResource==true javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil jar:file:/C:/ApacheNifi/nifi-registry-0.8.0/work/jetty/nifi-registry-web-api-0.8.0.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/javax/xml/bind/ServiceLoaderUtil.class
2021-07-15 10:51:24,630 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader WAP webapp loaded class javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil
2021-07-15 10:51:24,631 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader getResources META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory []
2021-07-15 10:51:24,631 DEBUG [main] javax.xml.bind Searching META-INF/services
2021-07-15 10:51:24,631 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader getResource META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext null
2021-07-15 10:51:24,631 DEBUG [main] javax.xml.bind Unable to load:META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
2021-07-15 10:51:24,632 DEBUG [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext isSystemResource==false org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ServiceLoader jar:file:/C:/ApacheNifi/nifi-registry-0.8.0/work/jetty/nifi-registry-web-api-0.8.0.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.3.jar!/org/glassfish/hk2/osgiresourcelocator/ServiceLoader.class
2021-07-15 10:51:24,632 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader WAP webapp loaded class org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ServiceLoader
2021-07-15 10:51:24,632 DEBUG [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext isSystemResource==false org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ServiceLoader$ProviderFactory jar:file:/C:/ApacheNifi/nifi-registry-0.8.0/work/jetty/nifi-registry-web-api-0.8.0.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.3.jar!/org/glassfish/hk2/osgiresourcelocator/ServiceLoader$ProviderFactory.class
2021-07-15 10:51:24,633 DEBUG [main] o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader WAP webapp loaded interface org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ServiceLoader$ProviderFactory
2021-07-15 10:51:24,634 DEBUG [main] javax.xml.bind Unable to find from OSGi: [javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.lookupUsingOSGiServiceLoader(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:58)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:309)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:478)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:435)
    at org.apache.nifi.registry.security.authorization.AuthorizerFactory.initializeJaxbContext(AuthorizerFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.nifi.registry.security.authorization.AuthorizerFactory.<clinit>(AuthorizerFactory.java:91)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:468)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:571)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:363)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:582)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:569)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:257)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.nifi.registry.jetty.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:481)
    at org.apache.nifi.registry.NiFiRegistry.<init>(NiFiRegistry.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.registry.NiFiRegistry.main(NiFiRegistry.java:164)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ServiceLoader.lookupProviderClasses1(java.lang.Class)" because "org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ServiceLoader._me" is null
    at org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ServiceLoader.lookupProviderClasses(ServiceLoader.java:108)
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

It does not look like a Nifi Registry problem on Windows. What is missing and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Forgot to include the link to "this article": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out Nifi Registry does come with JAXB implementation jar file under `<install-dir>\lib\java11`. However, since I am running Java 15, I suspect those are not loaded. I set log level to TRACE and confirmed that was indeed the case. Copying the jar files under `java11` folder to the `lib` folder resolved the issue for me.